# C++ add local variables to static vector without copying

Tags: c++

im trying to archieve the following in c++:
I want to be able to create local variables, add them to a global static vector and only pointers to them should be added to the vector.

In C# i was able to write (example):

```
public static List<Component> CACHE = new List<Component>(); //Somewere in class
//Now in method:
Component a = new Component();
a.Name = "Noël";
CACHE.Add(a); //Adds reference to CACHE a without copy
```

in c++ i see 2 solutions:

1.Use dynamic allocations:

```
static std::vector<Component*> CACHE; //Somewere in class

//Now in method:

Component* a = new Component();
a->Name = L"Noël";
CACHE.push_back(a);
```

the problem is that i dont want to use dynamic allocation because its slow.

2.My idea:

(Somehow i have to make the new operator private or just say in the documentation never use new on Component)

```
//somewere hidden:

std::vector<Component*> GLOBAL_CACHE;

//In method dont use new, instead we use a custom global function 

Component* a = CREATE_COMPONENT();

static std::vector<Component*> CACHE; //Example 

Component& ExampleRef;//Example 

a->Name = L"Noël";
CACHE.push_back(a);
ExampleRef = *a;
```

and now CREATE_COMPONENT():

```
Component* CREATE_COMPONENT()
{

GLOBAL_CACHE.push_back(Component()); //Add empty component
return &GLOBAL_CACHE[GLOBAL_CACHE.size() - 1]; //return pointer to construct added above. I think we now have everything on the stack and we just send around pointers to the stack object

}
```

Is my idea worth it or even working? Or should i just use dynamic allocation?

Comment: What do you mean by "it's slow"?

Comment: Someone told me dynamic alloations need something called a kernel call wich is slower than stack allocation - it needs more time to allocate

Comment: Did you actually profile your code? Is this the performance bottleneck?

Comment: std::vector's elements are stored in the heap anyway.

Comment: No i didnt profile my idea it but it is part of a game engine code and when a level loads there already taking place so much dynamic allocation. Currently it is working iwht dynamic allocation but loading takes long and im trying to reduce dynamic allocation everywere - because it it a small bottleneck

Comment: If you didn't measure the performance, you don't know where the bottlenecks are.

Comment: I did measure it but only with dynamic allocation with no i meant my own idea with the vector - sry. With dynamic allocation i can clearly see it is a bottleneck at the moment

Comment: The `push_back` is going to invalidate all previously calculated pointers. Also, it is not true that every dynamic allocation results in a kernel call.

Comment: You want a vector of pointers?  How about `std::vector <Component *>`.

Comment: the somebody told me something wrong :/ but when is a kernel call done?

Comment: @Paul sry i forgot the * atht he c++ samples D:

Comment: @xX_EASYHDLPMCAWPGOD_Xx Well, if you want to avoid copies, pass pointers or references around. Though take care not to _shoot your leg off_. Most probably you want to learn about standard c++ [dynamic memory management](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory) facilities.

Comment: I've got some news for you: your C# code uses dynamic allocation.

Comment: :F Really? I tought it would be using stack because its basically a local variable

Comment: @xX_EASYHDLPMCAWPGOD_Xx Stop comparing c# and c++ behaviors. These are fundamentally different.

Comment: i know but i have to archieve the same in c++ :/

Comment: The "same" in C++ uses the `new` keyword. Just like C#. You do understand that `new` does the logically equivalent operation in C# that it does in C++, except that C++ has automatically-scoped objects (what is colloquically described as "on the stack), which C# does not (unless the C# compiler can prove automatic scope semantics, which it can't assume by default, and it is rather difficult to prove most of the time).

Comment: But i tought that C# will use stack or heap allocation independent if its a reference type (class) or value type (struct). And "C++ has automatically-scoped objects (what is colloquically described as "on the stack)" does that mena that basically everything is on the heap? and stack objects are just automatically deleted when out of scope?

Comment: @xX_EASYHDLPMCAWPGOD_Xx _"And "C++ has automatically-scoped objects (what is colloquically described as "on the stack)" does that mena that basically everything is on the heap? and stack objects are just automatically deleted when out of scope?"_ As soon as you're introducing szes for allocations at runtime, c++ would deal with heap allocations natuarally. If you have all fixed sizes known at compile time, you might achieve _stack allocation_.

Comment: i see :) now i think ill use dynamic allocation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doing the same in C++ is not possible because of garbage collection. But you can do it similarly by using `shared_ptr<Component>` as the element type of your vector:

```
#include <memory>

std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Component>> CACHE;

// ...

auto a = std::make_shared<Component>();
a->Name = "Noël";
CACHE.push_back(a);
```

The Component will be automatically destroyed when there's no more references to it.

If you don't intend to store copies of the pointers somewhere else, but `CACHE` is the only place where you put them, then you can use `unique_ptr` instead:

```
#include <memory>

std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Component>> CACHE;

// ...

CACHE.push_back(std::make_unique<Component>());
CACHE.back()->Name = "Noël";
```

Unlike `shared_ptr`, `unique_ptr` can not be copied, only moved, meaning there can only ever be 1 reference to it. The Component object will be automatically destroyed when the `unique_ptr` is destroyed.

This is using memory allocation, but the same it true for C#.

Note that, unlike C#, using `new` and `delete` in C++ is a bad idea because they're prone to resource and memory leaks. Use `shared_ptr` and `unique_ptr` instead if you want to create objects on the heap.

Finally, you should read up on "C++ move semantics". You don't need to avoid putting things on the stack. You can move objects instead of copy them. Example:

```
#include <memory>

std::vector<Component> CACHE;

// ...

Component a;
a.Name = "Noël";
CACHE.push_back(std::move(a)); // No copy. The 'a' variable can no longer be used.
```

Moves are sometimes automatic and they are a big part of C++. But you need to educate yourself about it.